# How to add an image to the back of a custom checkbox

Tags: css, checkbox, slider, label

I found a really clean looking custom checkbox on codepen and just updated a project to use it. Right now I've got the background colors different for the different sections of my form, but I'd like to just make background an icon rather than just a solid color

The commented out stuff doesn't work

```css
.label-switch {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.label-switch::before,
.label-switch::after {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

.label-switch::before {
  width: 3em;
  height: 1em;
  border: 1px solid #757575;
  border-radius: 4em;
  background: #888888;
}

.label-switch::after {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: -20%;
  width: 1.5em;
  height: 1.5em;
  border: 1px solid #757575;
  border-radius: 4em;
  background: #ffffff;
}

.input-switch:checked~.label-switch::before {
  background: #00a900;
  border-color: #008e00;
}

.input-switch:checked~.label-switch::after {
  left: unset;
  right: 0;
  background: #00ce00;
  /*background-image:(url(http://pngimg.com/uploads/pokeball/pokeball_PNG8.png);*/
  /*background: url(http://pngimg.com/uploads/pokeball/pokeball_PNG8.png);*/
  border-color: #009a00;
}
```

```html
<input class='input-switch' type="checkbox" id="demo" />
<label class="label-switch" for="demo"></label>
<span class="info-text"></span>
```

Comment: Not sure I am understanding correctly, but is this what you're looking for? (yellow is a small placeholder image) -- https://codepen.io/JimmyJames88/pen/WVJzgq

Comment: yeah basically. The other dude who replied had the image where I was talking about. thanks for the reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything you did was correct it's just the background image needed to have a `background-position` and `background-size` set if you toggle the checkbox in my snippet you should see the background pattern as you intended it to work.

```css
.label-switch{
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
 }

.label-switch::before, .label-switch::after{
     content: "";
     display: inline-block;
     cursor: pointer;
     transition: all 0.5s;
}

.label-switch::before {
     width: 3em;
height: 1em;
border: 1px solid #757575;
border-radius: 4em;
background: #888888;
}

.label-switch::after {
     position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: -20%;
    width: 1.5em;
    height: 1.5em;
    border: 1px solid #757575;
    border-radius: 4em;
    background: #ffffff;
}

.input-switch:checked ~ .label-switch::before {
    background: #00a900;
    border-color: #008e00;
}

.input-switch:checked ~ .label-switch::after {
    left: unset;
    right: 0;
    background: #00ce00;
    background-image:url(http://pngimg.com/uploads/pokeball/pokeball_PNG8.png);
    background-size:contain;
    background-position:center;
    border-color: #009a00;
}
```

```html
<input class='input-switch' type="checkbox" id="demo"/>
<label class="label-switch" for="demo"></label>
<span class="info-text"></span>
```

Comment: how would you recommend implementing different images attached to different checkbox groups without completely needed to copy and paste the whole thing for each new image/color I want?

Comment: There are many different ways you could achieve this, I created a quick codepen with one example you could use :- https://codepen.io/aaronmcg/pen/RXyBqB

You could go deeper and use newer tech like css variables to change the colours on the fly, but it depends entirely on which browsers you are trying to support, so my method in the Pen is generally just for wider browser support.

Comment: that's incredible I can definitely teach myself what i want with this

Comment: quick question: why did you add that "visually hidden" bit on the top of the code pen? using your code as is shows up like so https://imgur.com/a/pTJqoBL why are those checkboxes showing up on the bottom like that?

Comment: So the visually hidden class was an accessible way to hide the checkboxes without hiding them from screen readers, if you add the class visually-hidden to your bottom set of checkboxes they will also disappear. If you were to just add `display:none;` it would mean screen readers would ignore the checkbox making your toggle inaccessible. you can read up more on this type of stuff here :- https://a11yproject.com/